# Get record from date to date using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to getting record from table , from date to date ,
 in table i have column  dateandtime field name `CreatedDate` and format is `2017-04-29 04:44:23` .
user select value will be like `04/27/2018`
Thanks

Comment: Not at all clear. Please specify clearly what are your table names, columns, datatype and provide a sample dataset and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `between` clause to speficy the whole day.

To get all records for `27th April 2018` the query could be

```
SELECT [columns] FROM table WHERE CreatedDate >= '2018-04-27 00:00:00' AND CreatedDate <= '2018-04-27 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to extract `date` part from `timestamp` to be used in `where` clause:

```
select * --Columns
from table1
where date(date_column) = DATE '2017-04-27' -- ANSI Date Literal
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/RRNT22054)**